# Different components, different quantities, different rules... too many!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have a product, which consists of two components, X qty of Component A, and Y qty of component B.

When I select it in the form or the user to edit it, I bring the default quantities, but I need to allow the used to edit X to any number they like, but if they choose to do so, I need to update my Y qty, to always be double of whatever they chose as the new X.

This is how the business rule looks for this product. There are many other products and each has its own number of components and interlinked quantities. What is the best way to manage this as the rules change quite often (and there's a lot of them)?

Someone suggested using JSON to validate at the server-side, but I'm quite new to this and I need some simple example at least to get me going on how this would be handled by the server and how it would look like.

I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need any server validations until the user actually presses Save or Update or whatever. When rendering the form for the user, include some simple js functions that handles the rules.

So if the user changes the value for X qty then set the Y qty to double that through onChange or onBlur events, all client-side. Then when user posts the data to the server, check if the quantities are valid by some custom validate callback in your model and raise an error if it is not.

Here is just an example of a model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  X_Y_RATIO = 2

  validate :x_y_ratio

private
  def x_y_ratio
    (self.y_qty / self.x_qty) == X_Y_RATIO
  end
end
```

So if the x_y_ratio method returns false then the product will not be saved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason why I think it should be done server-side is simply because there's too many rules and they actually change often. So leaving them in the app would be a bit hard to manage if I need to change something. Ideally only some fields would be editable, like X quantity, and if the user does this, then I automatically update Y to be double. I was even thinking storing the js text of each function in the db, if the product had some rules. and when you bring the product, it would bring this "rule" field,bring the text and somehow convert it into actual code to validate.

Comment: If the rules are so complicated that you want to store the entire functions, then I understand. I still think you should have validations in the models though, otherwise it can always be avoided. Instead of my approach with static ratios in the models, you could add another model called Rule which belong_to Product or even polymorphic associations to whatever model is in need of rules. That way the rules can be made dynamically but it still validated server side

Comment: How would this work when an application is in production? If I did have this model as you described, would this mean if one rule changes, I need to redeploy the entire app? (Let's say I have easy access to the server as it would be mine) would it be a matter of just changing one file in the system or much more complicated than that?

Comment: No, quite the opposite. You create one model called Rule. Then you save different instances of that model to the database, one instance for every model that needs rules. That way each model can be associated with a different Rule-instance. To make it dynamic, you will have to create an interface in the application so that you can change the rules when necessary (or update database manually)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Can I ask you? Since I have a lot of products with rules, maybe it would make sense to create a rule per product category instead, and having different validations for the products in that category? (that way i dont have 300 rule models :)) Would that make sense?

Comment: Absolutely, one Rule instance for every category. Totally makes sense :)